# How to prevent dataloss on restart of a influxdb server?

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb

im running a instance of influxdb on a relatively small device to collect time series IoT sensor data. Sometimes it is necessary to reboot that device (updates or something similar) and I noticed that after rebooting there is a dataloss in my influxdb history if I query some data. With my current config I lost around 16 hours of data due to a reboot.
How can I make sure all data is still present after a reboot of the device?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using? Are any non-standard configuration parameters being used? InfluxDB stores all points on disk by default.

Comment: Im using version 0.13 and a config which is default for most values except:
reporting-disabled = true
cache-max-memory-size = 5242880
cache-snapshot-memory-size = 512
[shard-precreation]
  enabled = false

and some paths for data storage as well as binding the http interface to localhost.

Comment: Do all the data storage paths ([meta] dir, [data] dir, and wal-dir) map to on disk storage? Also, the `cache-snapshot-memory-size` is extremely low (the unit is bytes).

Comment: The meta and the data dir are pointing to a disk storage (`/data/.influxdb/data`) while the wal-dir is pointing to `/tmp/.influxdb/wal` could this be a problem? I choose a very low `cache-snapshot-memory-size` because of the huge (1 week) dataloss when doing a reboot. After lowering this value the loss was much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

In InfluxDB, persistent data is stored in the `/wal`, `/data`, and `/meta` directories. The `/wal` directory contains the write ahead log, which acts as a staging area for recently written points to be stored before they are compressed into time series merge files for long term storage in the `/data` directory.

On Unix systems, the [`/tmp` directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_folder) is sometimes cleared on reboot. Since the `wal-dir` config setting is specified as `/tmp/.influxdb/wal`, the persistent data in the write ahead log may be cleared on reboot. This explains why you are seeing data loss on only recent data. Older data is flushed to the `/data` directory, which isn't cleared on reboot.

In short, the `wal-dir` config setting needs to be set to `/data/.influxdb/wal` or another directory that is not cleared on reboot.